# making a dictionary from a file with three columns

Tags: python, dictionary

If I am reading a file with three columns like so:

```
james     1.0    2.5

Tom       2.0    2.1

Ryan      3.0    2.5
```

I can't figure out how to make just the first column the key of my dictionary (as strings) and the next 2 columns (as floating-point numbers) my values. I know how to do it with only two columns but am confused on how to with 3.

This is my code so far:

```
def makeDict(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        sDict = dict(x.rstrip().split(None,1) for x in f)
        return(sDict)
        filename.close()
```

Comment: Is it gonna be three columns all the time?

Comment: yeah the actual file is 3 columns with like 120 words in each

Comment: the second and the third columns are gonna be inside a list with your first column as the key right? :-)

Comment: What do you mean "next 2 columns as values"? Each dictionary entry can only have one value. But that value could be a tuple or a list. Do you want the result `{'james':(1.0,2.5), 'Tom':(2.0,2.1), 'Ryan':(3.0,2.5)}`?

Comment: yes sorry^ the "value" for james should be [1.0,2.5]

Comment: So you want `{'james':[1.0,2.5], 'Tom':[2.0,2.1], 'Ryan':[3.0,2.5]}` where each value is a list?

Comment: it should be as a tuple

Answer (score 3):

```
dict = {}
f = open(file)
for line in f:
    line = line.split()
    dict[line[0]] = line[1:]
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    return {k:[v1,v2] for k,v1,v2 in (x.rstrip().split() for line in f)}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
def makeDict(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return {row[0]: [float(x) for x in row[1:]] 
                for row in (line.rstrip().split() for line in f)}
```

To break it down ...here we are reading in the lines and splitting them on whitespace

```
(line.rstrip().split() for line in f)
```

Then we are iterating over that and taking the first item as the key, while converting all others to floats.

Comment: is there a way to name this dictionary so i can call it later? if i want the dictionary to be named sDict so i can use it later where would i implement it in this code?

Comment: this worked but i want to be able to call this dictionary later

Comment: Then assign the return value from calling the function ... `sDict = makeDict(filename)`

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, read in the file, split on spaces, then create the dictionary using dictionary comprehension.

```
f = open("data.txt","r")
lines = list(map(lambda x: x.split(" "), f.readlines()))
f.close()

some_dictionary = { line[0]: (float(line[1]), float(line[2])) for line in lines}
```

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame({'col1header':list1, 'col2header':list2}, index = namelist)

Assuming namelist = [james, tom, ryan]

Comment: Along with your answer, please also explain what you are doing. [answer].